# Android: ParseUser with username shown on button after login

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am implementing ParseUser for user management.

### ParseUser login:

```
public void signIn(final View v)
{
    v.setEnabled(false);
    ParseUser.logInInBackground(mUsernameField.getText().toString(), mPasswordField.getText().toString(), new LogInCallback() 
    {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) 
        {
            if (user != null) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, First4.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0); // 0 for no animation
                LoginActivity.this.finish();
            } 
            else 
            {
                // Signup failed. Look at the ParseException to see what happened.
                switch(e.getCode()){
                case ParseException.USERNAME_TAKEN:
                    mErrorField.setText("Sorry, this username has already been taken.");
                    break;
                case ParseException.USERNAME_MISSING:
                    mErrorField.setText("Sorry, you must supply a username to register.");
                    break;
                case ParseException.PASSWORD_MISSING:
                    mErrorField.setText("Sorry, you must supply a password to register.");
                    break;
                case ParseException.OBJECT_NOT_FOUND:
                    mErrorField.setText("Sorry, those credentials were invalid.");
                    break;
                default:
                    mErrorField.setText(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    break;
                }
                v.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

### First Page:

```
// load user
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
btn_login.setText(""+ currentUser);
```

### Question:

After the user has login with valid username Peter and password abc123, it switches to the First4 page. I would like to show the username Paper on the button `btn_login`, however, it is now showing com.parse.ParseUser@42247001 instead of Peter.

How could that be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing so you are calling the default `toString()` method on the `ParseUser` object.
You need to retrieve the name from the `ParseUser` object like this:

```
// load user
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
btn_login.setText(currentUser.getUsername());
```

You can see the different method of this object [here](http://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html).